# How to change an environment variable and apply to all windows in a tmux session

Tags: tmux

I wonder is there any easy way that I can change an bash environment variable and apply to windows in a tmux session?

I've googled and didn't found a solution so I post the question here.

Thanks!!

Comment: Let me guess: you're looking for a way to set `$DISPLAY` for all windows after reattaching a session?

Answer (score 6):

You can't directly change the environment variables.

However, you can make shell terminals inside a tmux instance pick up new variables.  This requires a few steps.

First, tmux can update environment variables in itself. The `update-environment` configuration directive does this. Any variable listed here will be auto-udpated - connecting to a tmux session updates the session's environment variable with the value from the client you just connected.  So if you run `tmux attach`, and have `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` set, then the tmux session will get the new value of `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`.

However, that only updates the session's variables, so only new panes/windows will get the values. Existing windows will still have the old values. As @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams said, there is not a direct fix to this.

However, you can fix it in many programs.  Sufficiently recent versions of tmux have a `show-environment` command, which queries the session for the current values of an environment variable. This allows you to get the environment variable from within a program after it has been with the `update-environment` logic.

For instance, you can have some shells pick up the new value.  In ZSH, I do this with a `precmd` hook in `~/.zshrc`:

```
_update_ssh_agent() {
    local var
    var=$(tmux show-environment |grep '^SSH_AUTH_SOCK=')
    if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then
        eval "$var"
    fi
}
if [[ -n "$TMUX" ]]; then
    add-zsh-hook precmd _update_ssh_agent
fi
```

This makes it so that shells inside tmux sessions update the SSH agent every time they go to display a new prompt.  After I reconnect, all I have to do is hit enter at a prompt and it grabs the new SSH agent connection.

Bash also has a pre-command mechanism, although I do not know how to configure it off-hand. You could additionally configure more programs to use `show-environment` to update themselves, such as vim or emacs. However, you will need to configure each program you might want to do this with separately.

Answer (score 4):

So this is an old question, but came up when I was searching for what I wanted to do, so here's another solution.

When tmux is started, it copies the environment into a global environment.  When new windows are created, it merges the global environment with the session environment to set the environment for that window. We can view these environments with:

```
tmux show-environment [-g] [-t target-session]
```

Even better, we can also update the environments, even from within the windows' own tmux session:

```
tmux set-environment [-gru] [-t target-session] name [value]
```

For a full explanation of the flags, see the [tmux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tmux).

This feature was exactly what I wanted. Unfortunately it won't update the environment of existing shells, but we could easily loop over `tmux showenv -g` to re-export the tmux environment that might be set by another process.

---

Here was my use-case:

With the way I have my shell configuration set up, I export my environment in a login shell, and then exec into a tmux session. I figure since env vars don't change often, I don't need to source them in new non-login shells every time. However, when they do change, I don't want to restart my entire tmux session to have new tmux windows know about the change. While using the `update-environment` option and re-attaching solves a session restart, it's cumbersome to maintain an explicit list of potentially malleable env vars in my tmux configuration.

With the following function, we can update our environment variables in something like `~/.shenv` for example, and instead of sourcing the file (`. ~/.shenv`), we can *promote* the file (`promote ~/.shenv`) for new tmux windows to inherit from this updated environment.

```sh
promote() {
    sourced="$1"; shift
    . "$sourced"
    env - \
        "HOME=$HOME" \
        sh -c ". $sourced; env" | cut -d= -f1 | while read -r var; do
            val="$(eval "echo \"\$$var\"")"
            tmux set-environment -gt local "$var" "$val"
        done
}
```

What's happening here is we're sourcing our file from within a shell with an empty environment (apart from the `HOME` we add), and print out our new env vars. We pipe those into a `cut` to extract the variable of each line, storing it in a variable called `var`. After some meta magic with `eval` to get the indirect value of that variable from the current shell, we update our tmux target session. In this case, `local` is the name of our tmux session.

Answer (score 3):

No.

And there isn't even a hard way; manipulating the environment variables of another process is non-portable at best.

Answer (score 1):

After wrestling with different solutions, I came up with this bash function added to my .bashrc file:

```
if [[ -n $TMUX ]]; then
  _fix_ssh_agent_in_tmux () { if [[ ! -S $SSH_AUTH_SOCK ]]; then eval export $(tmux show-env | grep SSH_AUTH_SOCK); fi }
  ssh ()   { _fix_ssh_agent_in_tmux; command ssh $@; }
  scp ()   { _fix_ssh_agent_in_tmux; command scp $@; }
  rsync () { _fix_ssh_agent_in_tmux; command rsync $@; }
fi
```

If the shell is running within tmux, it redefines 'ssh' to a bash function that tests and fixes SSH_AUTH_SOCK before actually running the real ssh command.

Note that `tmux show-env -g` also returns a value for SSH_AUTH_SOCK but that one is stale, I assume it's from whenever the tmux server started.  The command above queries the current tmux session' environment which seems to be correct.

I'm using tmux 2.6 (ships with with Ubuntu 18.04) and it seems to work well.

Comment: another command I've found useful to add to the list is `git`: `if [[ -n $TMUX ]]; then ... git () { _fix_ssh_agent_in_tmux; command git "$@"; } fi`